# Getting all parameters and operations done by an exe

Tags: windows, powershell, ip, exe, tasklist

This may be a noob question but just for clarification.

For example I have any windows executable. How do I check what parameters or OS operations is done by it?

For example I can use `tasklist|findstr "notepad.exe"` but it only shows the PID and mem usage.

How do get an in-depth analysis. Like whether this exe is querying for my IP address and storing it or traversing my directories etc.

Wondering there are any tools that can be used other than reversing the exe to find out.

Comment: Google "malware analysis sandbox" :)

Comment: Take a look at Sysinternals' suite, nowadays provided by Microsoft.